# Changing the URL with jQuery without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change the URL with jQuery without reloading the page?

Comment: Change means complete new url or add few parameters to existing url?

Comment: Yes, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `location.hash`

jQuery has nothing to do with it though, this is basic DOM 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can only change the hash part of an url without a page refresh through `location.hash`. 
Adding get parameters (`?foo=bar`) or a complete url change will always reload the page.

In HTML5 you get more options to change URL's, but right now (2010) it's not yet viable since crappy browser die out hard.

Comment: Thats not strictly true any more. Check out the HTML5 history API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: @DanSingerman Which doesn't work with IE7/8 and thus still not viable imo. I would like it to be though, but I won't base my awnsers on it just yet.

Comment: -1: a fragmentidentifier (or hash) is a "real" part of the URL and can be changed from javascript. So, "You can"

Comment: I know. But when you give an absolute like you did, I think mentioning how technology is changing is a valid caveat. Remember this answer should be around for years.

Answer (score 0):

In general, leaving aside the new [HTML history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), you can't.

It is possible to add data to the URL after the hash (using `location.hash` as David Dorward describes). However, if you want to do this to affect behaviour of the page, you will also need to read these changes via jQuery (or triggered by the same process that sets the hash.)

Outside of the History API you will not be able to add a parameter, and have the page 'just know about it'.