# How to change the URL displayed in the browser without leaving the page

Tags: javascript, url, browser-history

Is it possible with JavaScript to change the browser's URL, but not leave the page?

Comment: You mean to change the text in the address bar without actually going there?

Comment: Please search the website first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+change+url+

Comment: Possible duplicate of *many* questions. For example: [Changing the URL with jQuery without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013122/changing-the-url-with-jquery-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381280/changing-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: ya probably should have searched first, sorry, slipped my mind

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In older browsers, you can **not** change the url in the address bar without leaving the page. But you can change the hash portion of the url without leaving the page. That is to say you can change `www.example.com` to `www.example.com#new_text` with JavaScript `window.location.hash = "new_text"`; everything after the `#` can be changed.

However, in HTML5 there is a new History API which allows you to change the part of the URL after the domain. So you still cannot change `www.example.com` to `www.BankOfAmerica.com` (for security reasons), but you can change `www.example.com/foo` to `www.example.com/bar`.

```
history.pushState("object or string representing the state of the page", "new title", "newURL");
```

Check [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) to see which browsers support HTML5 session history management and support the new `pushState` method.

In addition there is a JavaScript library which will normalizes the history API across browsers and changes the URL in new browsers and uses the hash portion for old browsers. See [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) .

Comment: yes, you can. i just don't know how. facebook does it, but of course they are super-programmers. Edit: just found out how here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955430/change-url-on-ajax-request

Comment: @Eduard Luca Thanks for showing me that, I've updated this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you are talking about the visible URL in the URL bar.

The answer is No, it is a major security vulnerability when an application tries trick users into thinking that are at another site.

Answer (score -2):

You can change anything after the hash mark (`#`) as this is frequently used in Ajax applications such as Google search and the new Twitter. (That's why everything appears after the hash mark in those apps.) But if you change anything else, the page will have to be reloaded.

Answer (score -6):

No, it's not possible. And, whenever it is possible, that is a browser bug (I know about previous security bugs related to this behavior, and they were fixed in past).

Actually... You can change the last portion of the URL, anything after the `#` character. But the hostname and path can't be changed without leaving the page.