# Change url on ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to add some `GET` parameters to the page URL. I am loading content like this:

```
$("#content").load("shop.pl #content .product", $.param({categ:1)}));
```

How can I change the URL to have the same parameter `?categ=1`?

Comment: Not sure you can do it without changing the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 [pushState API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) to achieve this. However, only the newest browsers support it and IE doesn't even support it yet in IE9. There was no way to do this previsouly. However, there is a convention that you would use location.hash to indicate a page which's state was modified by an ajax request.  For more information on how to use url hashes to indicate state on your page you might want to have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).

There is a library, [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js), which can be used for transition to pushState. It's API is very close to the pushState API, but it will transparently provide a hash fragement fallback if the browser does not support pushState.

Comment: +1 for same idea as me - only quicker (I was editing the question!) :-)

Comment: pushState API link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Your content is being loaded via AJAX, so perhaps the URL should have it's *hash fragment* modified - see http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html

Comment: OP wants to change GET parameters of the current website, not the hash part of the URL, I believe.

Comment: Yes, but this is not possible in browser that do not support the HTML5 pushState API, which are basicly all but the latest browsers. Manipulationg the hash fragment of an URL was *by convention* he way to go to indicate and restore the altered state of an webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manipulate the visible URL using `pushState()` method (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method), you may wish to read also about [`onpopstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate)).

That way you can change the URL in a way you wish.

Some demonstration on how to change URL without page reloading is here: http://html5demos.com/history