# How to change visible address

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to ask you if it is possible to change the visible address of my website on a certain domain.

Story:
I have a website and a domain. The link is kruzok.net/oliver/ any website.
So the address is the same: kruzok.net/oliver.
Question is if it is possible to change the upper address into a different address.
Only in a web browser of course.

I want an address visible on web browser be different without changing the domain.
So instead of kruzok.net/oliver it would be twitter.com

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What you are looking for is to have a large `iframe` opened on the page that loads twitter within it. You can try it, but with various security concerns with iframe settings, I'm not sure if it will work or not. But URLs will need to have a digital certificate though.

Comment: You cannot change the main part of the domain name which shows in the url on the browser address bar - this is a security issue. You can change the following part. This discussion may help: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089178/how-to-change-the-url-displayed-in-the-browser-without-leaving-the-page#:~:text=In%20older%20browsers%2C%20you%20can%20not%20change%20the,%22new_text%22%3B%20everything%20after%20the%20%23%20can%20be%20changed.

Comment: you can only change the relative path, if you could change the complete URL, you will break the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not possible, because it would be an incredible security concern if it were. For example, you could make a page look like a bank login page, and make the URL in the address bar look like, like the real bank

When the main domain is changed by whatever event the site is full reloaded

But you can change the href and slash sub routes:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Page Title", "/newURL");
```

Comment: Yes I understand what you want to tell me but in the meantime I found a specific way how I can do that. All I need to do is to write some commands into a .htaccess. The problem is that I do not know those commands.